# SPARQL: combining variables with literals

Tags: xml, variables, sparql, triplestore

Is it possible to create a subject in a SPARQL triple that is created by combining a variable and a literal?

My case is this:

```
OPTIONAL  
{
  $object dc:identifier $identifier .
  <info:fedora/abc:123/MODS> fedora-view:disseminationType $mods .
  <info:fedora/abc:123/TN> fedora-view:disseminationType $tn
}
```

$object looks like this: `<info:fedora/abc:123>`
$identifier looks like this: `abc:123`
and what I need is this: `<info:fedora/abc:123/MODS>`

I can't use `<info:fedora/$identifier/MODS>` but is there another way to 'glue' variables and literals together?

Answer (score 8):

With [SPARQL 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/), you should be able to use a combination of BIND(), STR(), IRI(), and CONCAT() to do what you want. Something like:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  $object dc:identifier $identifier .
  BIND(IRI(CONCAT(STR($object), "/MODS")) AS $new)
  $new fedora-view:disseminationType $mods .
  $new fedora-view:disseminationType $tn .
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's probably the solution. I'm using SPARQL with Mulgara and it seems like not all SPARQL functionality like CONCAT is supported yet (or I'm using an old version). I'll look into it.

Comment: Worked for me. I did not need IRI, so this was good enough:

BIND(CONCAT(STR(?var1), STR(?var2)) AS $concatenated)